What is Chromecom.android.chrome it came up on my history on my phone the chrome package doesn't generally look like that does it?
it came up on my history on my phone the package name isn't that is it?
Looking on the last visited sites on my teenagers phone and came up as Chromecom.android.chrome I've tried looking it up but comes back with just chrome

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
